# Proof involving retractions onto apartments

Tags: gr.group-theory, buildings

Let $\Delta$ be a (thick) building and let $\Sigma$ be an apartment. Let $C$ and $C'$ be adjacent chambers of $\Sigma$. Then $C$ and $C'$ have common wall $B \in \Sigma$. Since $\Delta$ is thick, there is another chamber $C'' \in \Delta$ that contains $B$ and since $\Sigma$ is thin we must have $C'' \not\in \Sigma$. There is an apartment $\Sigma'$ that contains $C$ and $C''$. Let $\phi : \Sigma \rightarrow \Sigma$ be the map
$$\rho(\Sigma', C) \rho(\Sigma, C') |_{\Sigma} $$ where we compose from left to right and $\rho(\Sigma', C)$ is the retraction onto apartment $\Sigma'$. Also there must be an apartment $\Sigma''$ which contains $C'$ and $C''$ and we define $\phi'$ similarly
$$ \phi' = \rho(\Sigma'', C') \rho(\Sigma, C)|_{\Sigma}. $$

We can show that $\phi(C')=C$ and $\phi'(C')=C'=\phi'(C)$. Let $D$ be any chamber in $\Sigma$ and let $G=\{C_i \}_{i=0}^m$ be a shortest gallery joining $B$ and $D$. We know that all $C_i \in \Sigma$. This implies that $C_0$ is either $C$ or $C'$.

I am trying to show by induction on $m$ that if $C_0=C$ then for $E \subset D$ we have

$\phi(E)=\phi(\phi'(E))=E.$

I can show that $\phi(E)=E$ for any $m$ but I am having trouble showing that $\phi(\phi'(E))=E$. Even for the case when $m=0$ and so $C_0=C=D$ I just cannot see how $\phi(\phi'(E))=E$.

Any help on this?

If you want more of a background where this is from, it is Group theory I by Suzuki and proposition 3.18 on page 322.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the fact that retractions are type-preserving, because they are defined using type-preserving isomorphisms between apartments. (See the argument used in the proof of (3.16) in Suzuki's book.)

In particular, in the case $m=0$ where $E \subset C$, you already know that $\phi(\phi'(C)) = C$, so $\phi(\phi'(E)) \subset C$. The only subset of $C$ of the same type as $E$ is $E$ itself, so you are done.

**Edit**:

Without using types, this seems to require a bit more detailed work. We can spell out $\phi(\phi'(E))$ as
$$ \rho(\Sigma, C') \rho(\Sigma', C) \rho(\Sigma, C) \rho(\Sigma'', C') (E) , $$
and now notice that the product of the middle two retractions $\rho(\Sigma', C) \circ \rho(\Sigma, C)$ acts as the identity on $\Sigma'$. However, $\rho(\Sigma'', C') (E)$ is contained in $C''$ and hence in $\Sigma'$, so we get
$$ \phi(\phi'(E)) = \rho(\Sigma, C') \rho(\Sigma'', C') (E) . $$
We now apply the same idea again: the product $\rho(\Sigma, C') \circ  \rho(\Sigma'', C')$ is the identity on $\Sigma$, and we conclude that indeed $\phi(\phi'(E)) = E$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The only problem is that type isn't defined yet and is only defined later, so I'm not sure if this is the argument Suzuki uses here??

Comment: @Anonmath101 Indeed, you are right. I have now also added a proof that does not rely on types.

Comment: Why does $\rho(\Sigma', C ) \circ \rho(\Sigma, C)$ act as the identity on $\Sigma'$?

Comment: Because its restriction to $\Sigma'$ is an isomorphism from $\Sigma'$ to itself fixing $C$ and all subsets of $C$; it then follows from Suzuki's (3.15) that it is the identity on $\Sigma'$.

Comment: Why is composition actually an isomorphism?

Comment: @Anonmath101 Are you asking why the composition of two isomorphisms is again an isomorphism? (Notice that by construction, the restriction of $\rho(\Sigma, C)$ to $\Sigma'$ is an isomorphism from $\Sigma'$ to $\Sigma$.)

Comment: I am wondering why the restriction of $\rho(\Sigma, C)$ to $\Sigma'$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: @Anonmath101 Well, to define $\rho(\Sigma, C)(D)$ for some $D \in \Sigma'$, you can take *any* apartment containing $D$ and an isomorphism $\varphi'$ from that apartment to $\Sigma$. This is independent of the choice of that apartment, as explained on p. 320. Now you simply make the same choice $\Sigma'$ itself, for any $D$, and so also the same isomorphism $\varphi'$. In other words, $\rho(\Sigma, C)$ coincides with $\varphi'$ on $\Sigma'$.